Is god having attributes that are infinite simpler than having finite attributes?
In his book The Existence of God, Richard Swinburne compares infinite “values” to any specific numerical value, claiming that the specific numerical value (say the speed of light) “cries out for an explanation of why there is just that particular limit, in a way that limitlessness [infinity] does not” (p. 97) He then further says that this is the primary means by which he can claim that the God hypothesis is very simple
I’m having trouble understanding why limitlessness would require less of an explanation than a particular limit. Can’t one simply ask “why are there no limits rather than some limit?” the same way one can ask “why is there this limit instead of another?” Intuitively, having attributes that are infinite seems more complex than less, although this is more of a side step to my main question.

I'd have to see the details, but it doesn't make sense to me either.

I don't think this is a correct reading. Pretty sure Swinburne means limitlessness as a/the attribute, not an infinite list of attributes.

Yes that is what I also mean @g By infinite attributes, I mean attributes that are infinite

The reason could be said to be very amorphous insofar as if the natural number system N stops at any limited finite numerical value n instead of n+1 then it's a much more involved problem than the standard model N which is ordinarily assumed to be infinite in size...

The speed of light is not trivial. If the speed of light were infinite the entire structure of the universe would change. This is the fine-tuning argument of the universe again. It needs to be finely balanced with the other constants in order to have a universe that allows for intelligent life to exist. I think Swinburne wants to suggest that infinities have a random quality to them, whereas the exact speed of light is finely tuned. Look at all those decimals...

The speed of light is actually exact - 299,792,458 in MKS, but exactly 1 in “natural” unit systems, along with G, h, and sometimes others. In this case c is actually a constant that the Universe could probably cope with a slightly different value of, but indeed it must be finite for anything to work.

@controlgroup It is exactly that number because in 1983 the meter was defined as the length of the path travelled by light in vacuum during a time interval of ⁠1 / 299792458 of a second.

I am aware. But there are also unit systems where it’s just 1, and also other not-completely-dead Universe configurations with c≈299792458 m/s. The issue of fine-tuning will come down to explaining why the cosmological constant has such a strange value, which will likely be revealed by a unified field theory/theory of quantum gravity.

@controlgroup Yes, but that is trivial. If it is 1, it is exactly 1.0000..., it doesn't get more precise that that.  But you are right that with the speed of light there is some leeway. Thanks for the input!
